# Could we re-open this SO question about OpenCloud?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I've edited ' [How can I generate a tag cloud in Java, with OpenCloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11481482/1075247) ' so that

1. it still fits the answer,
2. it still asks the question intended, and
3. it's useful to the community now.

Could it be re-opened please?

Comment: Voted to reopen. Nice edit

Comment: It still seems fairly not constructive to me in that it asks for a recommendation and as such if of the shopping or list-type. Besides that it already seems to have an accepted upvoted answer. Any particular reason you want to see this reopened?

Comment: I didn't peg it for a shopping question until now. I think the intent of my edit was to say "I want to do X, and I have Y, but it does it *this* way, and I want it done *this* way. Is it possible? If so how? If not what other options?" I guess that's still a shopping-esque question I guess. I want to re-open so that I can vote up the answer mainly.

Comment: ? You can still upvote the answer even if it's closed.

Comment: No one gets rep. Plus if the question is 'good' now (second edit this time) it shouldn't be closed, as it'll set a confusing example to anyone wanting to ask a similar question.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by the "no one gets rep" comment. Even if a question is closed, upvotes and downvotes still work as they usually would.

Comment: @Bart my mistake, I thought that closing a question mean that further voting wouldn't change the rep.

Comment: It's Open now..

Comment: @Pureferret Nope, voting still behaves the same. So no problem there. The last edit made it good IMHO. I made some minor corrections as well. If you do edit something, please take some time to correct even the little stuff. But well done overall. :) (Btw, voted to close this purely because it's resolved now)

Comment: @Bart Just glad I can still get rep once this is closed =p